# Android how to get Data from a JsonObject trough HttPos

Tags: java, php, android, json

This is the rustl of my php post query in my browser:

```
 {"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}
```

I think that this is a `jsonObject` because in phpScript i have encoded it in Json. Then my problem is that I want to get the result content in my Android apps.. note that I'm doing a simple login Android System.....

Now when I'm trying to get it in my Android code i get this exception: JSON Exception******
**Value <\ br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

and this is my Android code:

```
  //setting the valuesPairs
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

  //setting the valuesPairs
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameData));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailData));
  try {
      //setting up the default HttpClient
      HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

      /*setting up the POSTHttp methodd and parsing the url in case of online and the ip adress in case of localhost database
      and the phifile.*/
      HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.100:80/phpprojecttest/EmailLogin.php");


      //Parsing the NameValuesPairs inside the HttpPost
      System.out.println("************Opening URL And Setting POst PArm In it  ***********:" );
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      //getting the response      
      HttpResponse  response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);        
      response.getStatusLine();
      System.out.println("Le statut de votre requète est   :" +response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

      //Setting up the Entity         
      HttpEntity httpEntity=response.getEntity();
      inpuStream=httpEntity.getContent();     


      BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpuStream));  
      String line;


      // JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(inpuStream);

      String myres;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          reponseHTTP.append(line +"\n");
          System.out.println("*Reading***"+ reponseHTTP);
      }

      //on converti le text de la response dasn un Object Json
      JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(reponseHTTP.toString());      
      String stringObject=jsonObject.getString("message");// on prend la cle car on s'est au préalable que c'est un double

      System.out.println("********"+ stringObject);
      System.out.println("*******FUCK******"+reponseHTTP.toString());


  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      Log.e("ClientProtocol***********", e.getMessage());
  } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("IOExeption***********", e.getMessage());     
  /*} catch (JSONException e) {       
      Log.e("JSON Avecs Ses Erruers***********", e.getMessage());
  */ } catch (JSONException e) {
      System.out.println("*+JSON EXception*****"+ e.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i may be wrong friend, but i believe you are returning HTML code
 "*now when i'm trying to get it in my Adroide code i get this exception: JSON EXception****** Value <\ br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

you see where it says "Value **<\ br**" 
but the value you are trying to retreive is "{"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}" correct?

i suggest printing out the result of reponseHTTP.toString() and then making sure it is json before trying to convert. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick response to my question then I have just solve my problem

**I used the GetMethod to get My JSONObject cotent**  then it  worked  for me this is the full Working code...

```
//setting up the default HttpClient
                    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

                    /*setting up the POSTHttp methodd and parsing the url in case of online and the ip adress in case of localhost database
                    and the phifile.*/
                    HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.100:80/phpprojecttest/EmailLogin.php?name="+nameData+"&email="+emailData);


                    try {// on essay d'envoyer la requette
                        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                        //on verify si c'est okey via le status doit etre = 200 pour true
                        StatusLine statusLine= response.getStatusLine();
                        int statusCode=statusLine.getStatusCode();

                        if (statusCode == 200) {
                            HttpEntity  entity=response.getEntity(); // on recupere le corp de la requette qui contien du Json
                           // on lit le corp via InpuStream
                            InputStream content=entity.getContent();//ici onrecuper des données binaire
                            // onlit le corp du reponse ligne parligne
                            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));  //avecIpStreamReader on construit le caracteère et avec buffRea on construit la ligne
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                reponseHTTP.append(line);
                        }
                            System.out.println("---getting Code Statuts--- " +statusCode);
                            //on converti le text de la response dasn un Object Json
                            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(reponseHTTP.toString());

                            System.out.println("---Debut dgetting--- " +statusCode);
                            String prixFrom=jsonObject.getString("message");// on prend la cle car on s'est au préalable que c'est un double

                            System.out.println("*+++++++++++*"+ prixFrom);


                        } else {

                            System.out.println("*****************EUrror CODES " +statusCode);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        System.out.println("*******EUrrorJSON**" +e);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```